# How do I write custom function inside a child functional component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let me show you the code first for what I want to do

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Child(props) {
    useEffect(()=>{
        // var minutes = props.minutes
        let minutes = "420"
        
//how to write the following function in correct manner
        function convertMinutesToHours(minutes){
            var hours = minutes / 60
            var newHour = Math.floor(hours)
            var mins = (hours - newHour) * 60;
            var newMinutes = Math.round(mins);
            return newHour +":"+newMinutes; 
        }
    });

    return (
       <div>{convertMinutesToHours}</div>
    );
}

export default Child;
```

This code is self-explanatory sort of. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function Child(props) {
 function convertMinutesToHours(minutes) {
  var hours = minutes / 60;
  var newHour = Math.floor(hours);
  var mins = (hours - newHour) * 60;
  var newMinutes = Math.round(mins);
  return newHour + ":" + newMinutes;
 }
 useEffect(() => {
  // var minutes = props.minutes
  let minutes = "420";
  console.log(convertMinutesToHours(minutes));
 });

  return <div>{convertMinutesToHours}</div>;
}

export default Child;
```

You can declare Function anywhere inside Functional Component too or Globaly or in UseEffects.

Comment: Thanks @AryanSingh I guess I was mistaking in calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned with doing stuff the right way, better start with a linter.

Regarding this piece of code, `convertMinutesToHours` is clearly not logically tied to this component since it's a generic helper function, you should treat it as such by placing it either outside of your component in the same file, or, even better, **moving to a helper file** with other functions of similar nature to a separate folder: `lib`, `util` or how else you want to call it. You'll probably want to re-use it, so do not put it into the component.

Like this:

```js
// utils.js
export function convertMinutesToHours(minutes){
  var hours = minutes / 60
  var newHour = Math.floor(hours)
  var mins = (hours - newHour) * 60;
  var newMinutes = Math.round(mins);
  return newHour + ":" + newMinutes; 
}

// Child.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { convertMinutesToHours } from './utils';

function Child(props) {        
    return (
       <div>{convertMinutesToHours(props.minutes)}</div>
    );
}

export default Child;
```

As far as performance optimizations go, this approach is also better. Keeping the function inside the component in a manner described by Aryan in another answer will keep re-creating this function on each component render. If you do want to have it inside a component like Aryan suggests, at least wrap it into `useCallback`.

Having said that, do not overdo this by wrapping every single mapper function into `useCallback` or moving it all the way up, this will not make your code better performing or more readable.

Comment: Your answer is great I hope you don't mind I added a code example of what you suggested to help out

Comment: Thanks @SethLutske

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderMikhalchenko I will take that as a suggestion.